# PHP date calculate

Tags: php, date

Here is what i try to get. i need the date format in php as this : 2009-11-29

```
$startdate = (date("Y")-1) .'-'. date("n") .'-'. (date("j")-1);
$enddate = date("Y") .'-'. date("n") .'-'. (date("j")-1);
$myAnalytics->setDateRange($startdate,$enddate);    
echo 'Statistiques entre : ' . $startdate .' et ' . $enddate . '<br/><br/>';
```

i can get the current date, but i need to get the yesterday date (for google analytic)

so if today is 2009-11-29 removing 1 from 29 get me 28
but as today we are the 2009-12-01 i get the 0 as day...

I need to get the whole date, and remove one day, ans still get a valid date

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `date('Y-n-j', strtotime('yesterday'));`

Comment: You'll probably want 'Y-n-j' (without the spaces) to get the exact form listed.